# How would we generate a basis of sigmoidal functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions

I am trying to figure out how to generate a basis of sigmoidal functions. My issue is thus: there are several possible generating functions for a sigmoid (logistic curves, error functions, arctangent, etc.) that while generating a set of functions that are linearly independent is simple, I would not know how I would be able to ensure they span the set of all sigmoidal functions (especially since there are enough different ways to generate a sigmoid that I would be unable to ensure I accounted for all of them in the set). I am defining a sigmoid as an upper and lower bounded curve with either a strictly nonnegative or a strictly nonpositive derivative (or both, in the degenerate case of y = a constant) that always exists, with real solutions for all real number inputs.

So far, I have a set (that I reasonably positive is linearly independent) consisting of the following functions:

y = 1,

y = 1/(K + e^(-kx)),

y = erf(ax),

y = arctan(bx),

y = tanh(cx)

where K, k, a, b, and c are all constants, and k>0.

Comment: For clarity, you are looking to group together all curves from a series of families and use them as a basis for "sigmoids", where sigmoid is given by your definition above?  Is the span of this basis to be finite linear combinations or are you considering converging to elements of your set?

Comment: Yes to the first question. For the second, finite linear combinations.

Comment: Hmm, then I think you have an issue.  To say a general sigmoid equals a finite linear combination is the same as saying there is an analytic representation for all of them.  At best I think you can find a collection that is dense in them w.r.t to sum norm.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it further, I think converging to elements of my set is fine.

Comment: I should have said and above - finite linear combinations can be dense.  Then all I can suggest at this point is proving density and for that I would refer to the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem.